# An azure point to site VPN that was re-installed fails to install without an error message

Tags: azure, installation, vpn

When uninstalling an Azure point to site VPN it leaves remnant files in:

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections.`

The VPN does not appear in the VPN section of Network & Internet settings.

When the user tries to install the VPN package from the Azure Portal it will finish with no error message and fail to install the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this rare issue, the folders under connections can be deleted/moved. Once the folders are deleted/moved the install will complete and the VPN will show up in Network and Internet Settings. There's no need to copy the folders back.